# Are Microsoft DreamSpark Softwares Full Versions?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I want to download full versions of visual studio and SQL Server. Are the dreamspark versions full, or just express?

Comment: Also, you should accept answers to your questions if you've found them to be useful(See there is a tick there)and also use upvotes. It will help you get more answers.

Comment: @Rishabh Well sorrrrrrrrrry! Im at an internship right now and cant keep checking!

Comment: I mentioned that to you as it is a good practice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are the full versions.

> Q: What Microsoft software does this
>   site offer?
>
> A: DreamSpark has loads of products!
>   You can see the entire list by
>   visiting the DreamSpark home page all
>   of them are listed for easy access.
>
> Oh, and by the way? These are the
>   serious versions for serious people.
>   We’re talking, the big-time stuff.

https://www.dreamspark.com/FAQ/

Comment: "These are the serious versions for serious people" -- Code hard or go home /flex

Answer (score 3):

They are full versions.

Here are some extra characters since that answer is too short.

Answer (score 3):

They are full versions, but they aren't the highest versions.

In particular, they give VS 2010 Professional, not Premium or Ultimate.

Answer (score 2):

**Free products downloadable from DreamSpark**

Visual Studio Express 2010 and 2008 and SQL Server Express

Microsoft Robotics Developer Studio 2008 R3 and Microsoft CCR and DSS Toolkit 2008

XNA Game Studio 4.0

Virtual PC 2007

Windows Phone Developer Tools

Windows MultiPoint Mouse SDK

Windows Internet Explorer 9

Microsoft Small Basic

Kodu Game Lab

Microsoft Mathematics

**Free offers**
12-Month Academic Trial Membership to XNA Creators Club

One free Microsoft Certified Technical Specialist exam voucher

$99 waiver on Windows Marketplace for Mobile and first 5 submissions free

Microsoft IT Academy Student Pass (free e-learning courses to verified students)

Answer (score -1):

Yes they are full versions. Visual Studio 2015 is now on there as well as 2013

Make sure you register with visual studio to create a developer shared point.

Can be done [here](https://signup.live.com/signup?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=https%3a%2f%2faccesscontrol.windows.net%2f&wreply=https%3a%2f%2ftfsprodch1acs01.accesscontrol.windows.net%2fv2%2fwsfederation&wp=MBI_FED_SSL&wctx=cHI9d3NmZWRlcmF0aW9uJnJtPWh0dHBzJTNhJTJmJTJmYXBwLnZzc3BzLnZpc3VhbHN0dWRpby5jb20lMmYmcnk9aHR0cHMlM2ElMmYlMmZhcHAudnNzcHMudmlzdWFsc3R1ZGlvLmNvbSUyZl9zaWduZWRpbiUzZnJlYWxtJTNkYXBwLnZzc3BzLnZpc3VhbHN0dWRpby5jb20lMjZwcm90b2NvbCUzZHdzZmVkZXJhdGlvbiUyNmNhY2hlX2tleSUzZGU3c241Z3Rzd3dreDNjYmducDM3MnRnNmh1eHlnb3JldzRlcXIzYWZkcmYzbTJ6Z2RodHElMjZta3QlM2Rlbi1HQg2&cbcxt=eyJodCI6MywiaGlkIjoiYTVjYTM1ZWItMTQ4ZS00Y2NkLWJiYjMtZDMxNTc2ZDc1OTU4IiwicXMiOnsicmVhbG0iOiJhcHAudnNzcHMudmlzdWFsc3R1ZGlvLmNvbSIsInJlcGx5X3RvIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9hcHAudnNzcHMudmlzdWFsc3R1ZGlvLmNvbS9wcm9maWxlL3ZpZXciLCJta3QiOiJlbi1HQiJ9LCJyciI6IiIsInZoIjoiIiwiY3YiOiIiLCJjcyI6IiJ90&bk=1459342903&uiflavor=web&uaid=63c34df7014a465abdea11d7c7a74726&mkt=EN-GB&lc=2057&lic=1).

Hope this helps.